# Subquery returns more than 1 row MySql

Tags: mysql, query

Segue o código abaixo que está causando o erro citado no título:

```
select (select id from message where user_from = tempMsg.user OR user_to = tempMsg.user) as id from tempMsg
```

Como posso resolver? Alguém poderia me ajudar rápido?

Comment: O que exatamente você quer obter aí? Quer consultar em tempMsg um id pego de message?

Answer (score 0):

Em vez dessa subconsulta tente isso:

```
select a.id
from message a 
inner join tempMsg b
on a.user_from = b.user
and a.user_to = b.user
```

Comment: Creio que na cláusula ON deveria ser `OR` no lugar de `AND`, caso contrário irá pegar apenas as mensagens enviadas por um usuário para ele mesmo.

Comment: Considere adicionar explicações comparativas sobre o código dele e seu código, para facilitar o entendimento de sua solução.